# are variables recalculated when they are used in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

im trying to make a random number generator using time for a question generator but the sum changes after i type something in the console. the only thing i can think of is if it recalculates variables involving time every time they are used. im using dotnetfiddle.net

```
Imports System 

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim number1 As Integer = ((System.DateTime.Now.second )/(System.DateTime.Now.Minute + 1))
        Dim number2 As integer = (((System.DateTime.Now.Second)/System.DateTime.Now.Hour)*System.DateTime.Now.Month + System.DateTime.Now.Day)
        Dim answer As Integer = number1 + number2
        Dim Guess As Integer = Nothing
        Console.WriteLine("what is " & number2 & " + " & number1 & "?")
        Guess = Console.ReadLine
        If Guess = answer
            Console.WriteLine("Well Done")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Unlucky")
        End If
        
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why `answer` would be changing after reading from the console in your program.  Have you stepped through with breakpoints to make sure this is actually happening?  Also you may want to look in to the [`Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8) class for getting random numbers.

Comment: I have only noticed this behavior when using DotNetFiddle and not in Visual Studio.

I believe it has to do with with the they they're compiling the code.

Comment: Also, you need to account for if the second or hour is 0 so that you don't get a divide by 0 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, turn on Option Strict now and for every project.

When you do division, the compiler assumes you can produce a double not an integer. There is such a thing as the back slash \ integer division operator. This simply discards any value to the right of decimal point.

Now let's look at how `number1` is generated. The numerator can be 0 to 60 and the denominator can be 1 to 61. Running the program 3 times, I get 55\20 =  2 23\21 = 1  and 39\23 = 1. The smallest numerator 0 with the largest denometer, 61, will produce 0. The largest numerator, 60, with the smallest denometer, 1, will produce 60. If the denominter > then the numertor we get 0. The denominator must be 1/2 or less  of the numberator to get a number greater than 0. As you can see this not really that random.

The .net framework provides a Random class. Declare a new instance of the class outside of Sub Main as a Module level variable. Then use the .Next method to produce your randoms.

```
Private Rnd As New Random

Sub Main()
    Dim number1 = Rnd.Next(0, 100)
    Dim number2 = Rnd.Next(1, 100)

    Dim Answer = number1 + number2
    Console.WriteLine($"what is {number2} + {number1} ?")
    Dim Guess = CInt(Console.ReadLine)
    If Guess = answer Then
        Console.WriteLine("Well Done")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Unlucky")
    End If
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```